# Refraction through converging lens: finding image distance and image height

Tags: refraction, lenses

So in this situation there is a 1.79 meter tall person standing 30 meters from a 150 mm converging lens and I'm trying to find where the image will form and how tall it will be. **My problem is in finding the image height.**

Converting everything to centimeters we have:

- **Object height** = 179 cm
- **Object distance** = 3000 cm
- **Lens focus** = 15 cm

[image]

So to find image distance (*di*) I used the following equation:

[image]

And then plugged in the values above:

[image]

So far so good, the image distance is similar to what we would expect. **The problem arises when trying to find the image height, it should be negative but for some reason isn't.**

So I started with the equation relating object height and image height to object distance and image distance:

[image]

Then I plugged in values to find *h<sub>i</sub>*:

[image]

*h<sub>i</sub>* **should** be negative because any converging lens is going to invert the image.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Its really just the use of signs... $d_o$ will be taken as positive in the formula if the object is real (which it is in this case). Also, $d_i$ is positive if the image is real (which it is). Using a coordinate system is not the way you solve these problems, you have to consider the nature of the object and the image when plugging in values. If you use the convention I mentioned, the problem will work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sign conventions for doing lens calculations. In the [Gaussian sign convention](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenseq.html) the object distance, $u$, is positive to the left of the lens and the image distance, $v$, is positive to the right of the lens. So in the Gaussian sign convention $u = +3000$cm. With this convention the lens equation and the the magnification are given by:

$$ \frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{f} \tag{1} $$

$$ M = -\frac{v}{u} $$

In the [Cartesian sign convention](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenseq.html#c2) and distance to the left of the lens is negative and any distance to the right of the lens is positive. So in the Cartesian sign convention $u = -3000$cm. With this convention the lens equation and the the magnification are given by:

$$ \frac{1}{v} - \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f} \tag{2} $$

$$ M = \frac{v}{u} $$

You've managed to get the two mixed up because you have $u < 0$, which is the Cartesian convention, but you've used the Gaussian form of the lens equation (1). So your value for the image position is wrong.

It should be obvious your answer was wrong because you got $v = 14.925$cm, but for a real image $v$ is always greater than $f$ so your answer for $v$ should be greater than $15$cm.

Anyhow, I recommend sticking to the Cartesian sign convention because it's more logical. So take $u = -3000$cm as you did, but use equation (2) to calculate $v$ and then the magnification. You'll find the magnification comes out negative as you'd expect.

Comment: How can i get the image? Is there any equation to get the images the will form when we place it in different distance way from the camera??